# R: combine all strings in group in one row

Tags: r, string, group-by

I have the following dataframe:

```
               Date          Day    Element    Variable    Failure
2021-03-01 08:00:00   2021-03-01          A     Current          1
2021-03-01 08:00:00   2021-03-01          A     Voltage          1
2021-03-01 08:10:00   2021-03-01          A     Current          0
2021-03-01 08:10:00   2021-03-01          A     Voltage          0
2021-03-01 08:20:00   2021-03-01          A     Current          1
2021-03-01 08:20:00   2021-03-01          A     Voltage          1
2021-03-02 08:00:00   2021-03-02          B     Current          1
2021-03-02 08:00:00   2021-03-02          B     Voltage          0
2021-03-02 08:10:00   2021-03-02          B     Current          1
2021-03-02 08:10:00   2021-03-02          B     Voltage          0
2021-03-02 08:20:00   2021-03-02          B     Current          1
2021-03-02 08:20:00   2021-03-02          B     Voltage          0
```

After grouping it by `Day` and `Element`, I want to generate a column combining the strings from the column `Variable` in a comma-separated string, if at least one row in each group has `Failure == 1`. So I am looking for this output:

```
       Day    Element        Combination
2021-03-01          A    Current,Voltage
2021-03-02          B            Current
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try `aggregate` like below

```
aggregate(
  variable ~ Day + Element,
  subset(
    df,
    Failure == 1
  ),
  function(x) toString(unique(x))
)
```

Comment: Works almost perfectly but it duplicates the column ´Element´ with the same name, so if then I do ´df = df %>% dplyr::select(-Element)´, both columns are removed. Any idea how to remove just one?

Comment: Alright, I got it with ´df = df[ -c(2) ]´, being 2 the index of one of the duplicated columns

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyr`'s functions `pivot_wider`and `unite`.

```
df %>% group_by(date, Element, Variable) %>%
        summarise(Failure=max(Failure)) %>%
        pivot_wider(names_from=Variable, values_from = Failure) %>%
        mutate(across(Current:Voltage, ~ifelse(.x, deparse(substitute(.x)), NA))) %>%
        tidyr::unite(col='Combination', Current:Voltage, na.rm = TRUE, sep=", ")

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   date, Element [2]
  date       Element Combination     
  <date>     <chr>   <chr>           
1 2021-03-01 A       Current, Voltage
2 2021-03-02 B       Current
```

**data**

```
df<-tibble(date=as.Date(c("2021-03-01","2021-03-01", "2021-03-01", "2021-03-01", "2021-03-02", "2021-03-02", "2021-03-02", "2021-03-02")),
           Element=c('A', 'A', 'A',"A","B", 'B', 'B', 'B'),
           Variable=rep(c('Current', 'Voltage'), 4),
           Failure = c(1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0))

# A tibble: 8 x 4
  date       Element Variable Failure
  <date>     <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>
1 2021-03-01 A       Current        1
2 2021-03-01 A       Voltage        1
3 2021-03-01 A       Current        0
4 2021-03-01 A       Voltage        0
5 2021-03-02 B       Current        1
6 2021-03-02 B       Voltage        0
7 2021-03-02 B       Current        0
8 2021-03-02 B       Voltage        0
```

**Edit**
A somewhat simpler approach:

```
df %>% mutate(Combined=(ifelse(Failure==1, Variable, NA))) %>%
        group_by(date, Element) %>%
        summarise(Combined=paste(unique(na.omit(Combined)), collapse = ', '))%>%
        ungroup()
```